# An Excel Ribbon via VSTO solution explorer folder structure vs. path in code

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, path, add-in, ribbon

I am following [this](http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/create-excel-2007-vsto-add-in-ribbon.aspx) tutorial for adding an Excel Ribbon via VSTO. 
My problem is exactly the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778994/having-trouble-adding-a-ribbon-control-to-my-outlook-2010-addin) one. I have visited the links, but it didn't help me. The answer is very poor and leaves me clueless in terms of how to solve this issue.
If I add a Ribbon Item straight to the Project I am able to compile and run the add-in. However, when I add a new folder then stick a new item(Ribbon) inside of that folder I am getting an error. I think it's related to the path'ing. 
Somewhere, somehow I have learned that Visual Studio 2012 uses an *intelligent folder structure* (sorry for this poor naming) which means that it looks for files in default directories etc. If you change the structure then you have to edit a file(i dont know which one) and specify your new path to it. I am suspecting the above to be the issue.

Solution Explorer folder structure:
[image: Solution Explorer Folder Structure]
The error msg:

> ```
> > 'MyAddIn.Ribbon.ThisRibbonCollection' does not contain a definition
> > for 'GetRibbon' and no extension method 'GetRibbon' accepting a first
> > argument of type 'MyAddIn.Ribbon.ThisRibbonCollection' could be found
> > (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> ```

The code:

```
partial class ThisRibbonCollection
{
    internal MyCustomRibbon MyCustomRibbon
    {
        get { return this.GetRibbon<MyCustomRibbon>(); }
    }
}
```

My question is: What code do I have to modify (namespace?) in order to point the partial class to the right location?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ha! I have just realised there is a **very simple** work around to this problem. I am sure there are other ways, possibly more complicated and requiring coding, to solve this issue but why would you want to complicate your life in first place? :) I think this solution generally applies to anyone with a similar problem. 
I remember reading *[`ASP.NET 4.5 IN C# and VB.NET`](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-ASP-NET-4-5-in-C-and-VB.productCd-1118311809.html)*. The author introduces you to the Visual Studio in great detail and explains how to use the *`Solution Exlorer`*. I realized it was possible to move files around in the Solution Explorer while Visual Studio would automatically update all **`references`** for us. 
 I was able to compile and run the Project when I added the file straight to the Project as a new item (Ribbon[Visual Designer]). When I created a new folder in the Project Solution called *Ribbon* **and then** right-clicked and added a new item I was getting error. So, instead of adding the new file to the *Ribbon* folder, I added it straight to the Project and then simply dragged it to the *Ribbon* folder. Boo! The project compiled and ran with no errors! 
I can't believe I haven't thought of it in the first place -> I guess I got too carried away following the [tutorial](http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/create-excel-2007-vsto-add-in-ribbon.aspx)...

Steps:
Add a new folder called *`Ribbon`*
[image: Adding a new folder to the Project]
Right click MyExcelAddIn > and a new item *`Ribbon`* (Visual Designer)
[image: Right click the]
Drag and drop *`myRibbon.cs`* into the *`Ribbon`* folder
[image: drag and drop]

compile and run! Enjoy

Comment: Thanks, this was super helpful.  Just seems like a bug somewhere in VS.  But great to have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the namespace was wrong in the ribbon.designer.cs class (it was a ribbon copied from a differnet project, so it had the other project namespace name).

Changed the namespace to what it should be fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to provide a bit more detailed explanation of this problem.

`ThisRibbonCollection` class stored inside `MyCustomRibbon.Designer.cs` is a partial class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods), meaning that content of this class can be kept in different cs files.
The other part of `ThisRibbonCollection` class exists inside `ThisAddIn.Designer.cs` and looks like:

```
internal sealed partial class ThisRibbonCollection : Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonCollectionBase {
    internal ThisRibbonCollection(global::Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonFactory factory) : 
            base(factory) {
    }
}
```

At compile time, partial classes are merged. It means that one partial class can use methods/fields defined in the other partial class. In our case `ThisRibbonCollection` from `MyCustomRibbon.Designer.cs` uses method `GetRibbon` that is defined in the base class of the `ThisRibbonCollection` from `ThisAddIn.Designer.cs`.

But partial classes will be merged only if all the partial class definitions are in the same namespace.

When the ribbon is moved to a separate folder the namespace gets automatically updated. That is why class `ThisRibbonCollection` cannot find '`GetRibbon`' method. Because it is not merged with the other partial class anymore.

**Solution:**

1. At the end of `MyCustomRibbon.Designer.cs` create a namespace section with a root-namespace of the add-in (the same namspace that is used inside `ThisAddIn.Designer.cs`)
2. Move there `ThisRibbonCollection`:

The code should look like:

```
namespace root-namespace
{
    partial class ThisRibbonCollection
    {
        internal forms.ELRibbon Ribbon1
        {
            get { return this.GetRibbon<forms.ELRibbon>(); }
        }
    }
}
```